# how can set to variable from expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I want to start the python script with the tcl script and wait for the python script to finish. At the end of the Python script there is an edition and I would like to capture it.

The output from test.py is as an example:

```
done testdir1 testdir2 testdir3
```

I would like to put testdir3 in a variable.

```
bind pub "-|-" !dir pub:dir
proc pub:dir {nick host handle channel arg} {
    spawn python test.py
    expect  "done" {putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :match"}
    putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :done"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the subprocess script is just going to run, print something out at the end of relevance, and then finish, the easiest way to run it and capture (all) the output is with the built-in `exec` command:

```
bind pub "-|-" !dir pub:dir
proc pub:dir {nick host handle channel arg} {
    set output [exec python test.py]
    if {[regexp -line {^done (.*)} $output -> names]} {
        # Not quite sure what you want to do with the rest of the output
        putnow "PRIVMSG $channel $names"
    }
    putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :done"
}
```

The `-line` option to `regexp` is used because `$output` may hold multiple lines, and we're looking for a particular one of them.

Comment: If it's going to take a long time to run, that's trickier as you get into the domain of needing asynchronous processing. But anything taking a fraction of a second can probably be handled in a straight-forward way like this, especially if expected traffic levels are low.